# UIFontMetrics bug when used on textStyle of .body

Tags: swift, xcode, fonts, uifont

I am trying to figure out how to use UIFontMetrics.  From my understanding, the following code is supposed to set the default font size to be 50 unless the user changes their preferred display font size, shrinking or growing the font based on their settings.

`let font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body).withSize(50))`

When I run my app the font is smaller than 50.

Testing:

1. If I use `font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body).withSize(50)` I get the correct size when the program runs. So I know that the text is in fact shrinking for the default size with UIFontMetrics.
2. So I tried to adjust the .withSize parameter from 50 to 200 thinking that maybe the scaling ratio for UIFontMetrics was shrinking the font.
   `let font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body).withSize(200))`
   The font size did not change.
3. Next I used .largeTitle for the forTextStyle option to try and get the desired font size.
   `let font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .largeTitle).scaledFont(for: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle).withSize(50))` .
   This fixed the font size.
4. Last I wanted to check to see if adjustment of the .withSize parameter from 50 to 200 would work with .largeTitle.
   `let font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .largeTitle).scaledFont(for: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle).withSize(200))` .
   This grew the font size.

This leads me to believe that unless I have missed something, there is a bug where withSize does not change the size if used on UIMetrics with text style option .body.

Comment: Have same issue

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't know the exact answer,  but I think you should add this method, from UIFontMetrics class.

```
func scaledFont(for: UIFont, maximumPointSize: CGFloat) -> UIFont
//Returns a version of the specified font that adopts the current font metrics and is constrained to the specified maximum size.
```

This maybe will fix the issue.